# start date end date in python validation

Tags: python, datetime, validation

1)get date as a string from user
2)convert to date object
3)find the first and last date of the month
4)append the list in the given format
5)find the next month of the date
6)repeat the step 3 and 5 until the date is lesser then the end date
Sample Input:

```
02/12/2022, 24/02/2023 (Check and validate the start , end dates)
```

Sample Output:

```
[
            {'year': 2022, 'month': 'Dec', 'start_date': "01/12/2022", 'end_date': "31/12/2022", 'days': 31},
            {'year': 2023, 'month': 'Jan', 'start_date': "01/01/2022", 'end_date': "31/01/2023", 'days': 31},
            {'year': 2023, 'month': 'Feb', 'start_date': "01/02/2022", 'end_date': "28/02/2023", 'days': 28}  
]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: if i choose date it will show the start date and end date of the month here i attached my sample output in [body]

Comment: Please format your question body a bit more so that it becomes more understandable

Comment: sure..! now i add briefly  my  question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.